# How should I structure a deep linking config object to work with these navigators?

Tags: ios, react-native, react-navigation, deep-linking

Given the following navigator hierarchy, what is the correct way to structure the linking config object? As currently constructed, when trying to open 'myapp://bizpage/1', I get this error:

The navigation state parsed from the URL contains routes not present in the root navigator. This usually means that the linking configuration doesn't match the navigation structure. See https://reactnavigation.org/docs/configuring-links for more details on how to specify a linking configuration.

I followed the documentation and attacked google all evening. I don't see where I am going wrong here.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

```js
function AppNav({navigation}) {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="AuthFlow"
        component={AuthFlow}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="DrawerNav"
        component={DrawerNav}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

```js
function AuthFlow({navigation}) {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Login"
        component={Login}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Signup"
        component={Signup}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

```js
function DrawerNav({navigation}) {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator>
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={Main}
      />
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="Profile"
        component={Profile}
      />
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="Notifications"
        component={NotificationsScreen}
      />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}
```

```js
function Main({navigation}) {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="HomeScreen"
        component={HomeScreen}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="BizPage"
        component={BizPage}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="PeerProfile"
        component={PeerProfile}
      /> 
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

```js
const App = props => {
const linking = {
    prefixes: ['https://myapp.com', 'myapp://'],
    config: {
      screens: {
        AppNav: {
          screens: {
            DrawerNav: {
              screens: {
                Home: {
                  screens: {
                    BizPage: {
                      path: 'bizpage/:id',
                      parse: {id: Number},
                    },
                    PeerProfile: {path: 'peerprofile/:id', parse: {id: Number}},
                  },
                },
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  };

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <NavigationContainer
        linking={linking}
        theme={DarkTheme}
        fallback={<Text>Loading...</Text>}>
        <AppNav></AppNav>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have a screen named `AppNav`. It's a component. The linking configuration should only contain screen names.

The screen that should be under config is `DrawerNav`

```js
config: {
  screens: {
    DrawerNav: {
      // ...
```